# IndexError: string index out of range using python 3.7

Tags: python

I checked similar posts but couldn't find any that solved my problem. The for loop that is commented out in my code produces correct output telling me that the indices I expect for a given sentence are correct.

The program asks for a couple of sentences and then capitalizes the first letter of the first word in the sentence.

```
def main():
    sentence = input('Enter a few sentences (with periods to end them) ')

    s = capitalize_sentence(sentence)

    #print(s)

def capitalize_sentence(s):
    sentences = s.split('.');
    result = ''

    for sentence in sentences:
        # these print as expected no index errors
        #for i in range(len(sentence)): 
        #    print(i, sentence[i])

        if sentence[0] == ' ': # assuming 1 space separates sentences
            result += ' '
            result += sentence[1].upper()
            result += sentence[2:]
            result += '.'
        else:
            result += sentence[0].upper()
            result += sentence[1:]
            result += '.'

    return result

main()
```

The traceback output is:

> > > > Enter a few sentences (with periods to end them) howdy. how are you. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> > > >         "C:/Old_Data/python/book/ch08/ch08_ex08_sentence_capitalizer.py", line
> > > >         29, in 
> > > >             main()   File "C:/Old_Data/python/book/ch08/ch08_ex08_sentence_capitalizer.py", line
> > > >         4, in main
> > > >             s = capitalize_sentence(sentence)   File "C:/Old_Data/python/book/ch08/ch08_ex08_sentence_capitalizer.py", line
> > > >         17, in capitalize_sentence
> > > >             if sentence[0] == ' ': # assuming 1 space separates sentences IndexError: string index out of range

Thanks for any help you can provide.

EDIT: the string I provided was: howdy. how are you.

Comment: Would you be able to supply a sample `sentence` input? This is solvable. I want to make sure it works on the input you choose

Comment: @Abhishek  I edited my post to show a string I provided as input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting empty strings as a result of your split:

```
"howdy. how are you.".split('.')  # = ['howdy', ' how are you', '']
```

You are getting an exception when you are trying to get the `[0]`th character of an empty string. In your loop, you should check if the sentence is not empty and skip it (for example, using `continue`) if it is:

```
for sentence in sentences:
    if not sentence:
        continue
    elif sentence[0] == ' ': # assuming 1 space separates sentences
        result += ' '
        # etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a input string where splitting leaves you with a sentence that has zero chars.

That makes your `sentence[0]` fail because `sentence` is the empty string `""`. You can't get the first char of a empty string. You get `IndexError: string index out of range`.

The `for` loop you commented works, because when the string is empty, it will never enter the inner code block. It will just be skipped printing nothing.

That's how I would write the function:

```
def capitalize_sentence(s):
   return '. '.join(text.strip().capitalize() 
       for text in s.split('.') if text.strip()) + '.'
```

Testing it:

```
>>> capitalize_sentence("howdy. how are you.")
'Howdy. How are you.'
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem and I solved it by checking for the empty string and continue if empty.

Comment: @ChrisCharley check my elegant, concise solution for your problem. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two options for fixing your function:

```
def capitalize_sentence(s):
    sentences = s.split('.');
    result = ''
    for sentence in sentences:
        for i, char in enumerate(sentence):
            if char == ' ':
                result +=' '
                continue
            result += char.upper()
            result += sentence[i+1:]
            result+='.'
            break
    return result

def capitalize_sentence(s):
    sentences = s.split('.');
    result = ''
    for sentence in sentences:
        while sentence:
            result += sentence[0].upper()
            if sentence[0] != ' ':
                result += sentence[1:]
                result+='.'
                break
            sentence = sentence[1:]
    return result
```